# Dynamically create contents of IN operator SQL php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli, prepared-statement

Is it possible to use prepared statements with either MySQLi or PDO and still be able to dynamically add items to the IN part of the query, for example...

```
$somearray = ['tagvalue1', 'tagvalue2', 'tagvalue3'];
$sql = "SELECT foo FROM bar 
            WHERE tag IN(?)";
```

I ask this because I have a situation whereby the number of elements in the IN part is not known until runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You asked:

> Is it possible to use prepared statements with either MySQLi or PDO
>   and still be able to dynamically add items to the IN part of the
>   query, for example...

**No**, unfortunately it is not. It happens that ColdFusion does this, but not php.

Answer (score 0):

While you can't do exactly what you want with a prepared query, you can dynamically generate the $sql string for the query to accomplish the same thing.

Given some array $array = (n, n1, n2, ... nN)

```
$sql = "SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE tag IN (";
foreach($array as $value) {                 
    $sql .= "'" . $value . "', ";
}
// Strip off the last comma and space from the IN clause 
$sql = substr($sql, 0, strlen($sql) - 2);
$sql .= ")";
```

It's certainly not the most elegant solution and you'll have to do some more data validation or escaping of dangerous characters that a prepared query would handle better, but it will do the job.

As a side note, there are ORM (Object Relational Mapper) libraries that support things like accepting an array of values to generate the IN clause in a database statement. Propel is the one I have most experience with, but I'm sure others like Doctrine would have a similar method.

A propel-ish example would be like

```
$results = BarQuery::create()
    ->select('foo')
    ->filterByTag(array($value1, $value2, ..., $vauleN)
    ->find();
```

Lots of added functionality and support, but does increase your initial set up time for a project.